# I am stuck when trying to activate database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to activate the database by using my user account. However, after I reset all the username and passwords from the command prompt using sql commands, I could access the phpmyadmin site but could not activate when I try to add a new database. Anyone could figure out what is the problem that the phpmyadmin could not work as expected?

[image: Error occurred when trying to add a database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After resetting username & password try to :

1. Kill the session of phpmyadmin
2. Start the service again
3. Login to phpmyadmin as root with your new password